# Why using ':remote config timeout none' is still giving timeout error in gremlin with Janusgraph

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

I have tried to run the following query, but still receive timeout error.

```
gremlin> :remote config timeout none
==>Remote timeout is disabled
gremlin> mgmt.updateIndex(mgmt.getGraphIndex("byUserNameType"), SchemaAction.REINDEX).get()
Evaluation exceeded the configured 'evaluationTimeout' threshold of 300000 ms or evaluation was otherwise cancelled directly for request [mgmt.updateIndex(mgmt.getGraphIndex("byUserNameType"), SchemaAction.REINDEX).get()] - try increasing the timeout with the :remote command
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]N
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The :remote config command applies to the gremlin client and leaves the timeout settings of Gremlin Server untouched.
To make your reindex happen via a remote connection, you have to increase the evaluationTimeout setting of Gremlin Server in the conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server.yaml file (or set evaluationTimeout to 0 to disable it).
https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_configuring_2